# Arduino how to count external interrupts inside array of objects?

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt-handling, esp32

## PROBLEM

I'm starting to play with Arduino IoT (ESP32). I read the GPIO configuration from a file on the SD card. I have a problem with external interrupts. I need to count the number of interrupts on a given GPIO.

I wrote a class that stores the GPIO configuration, and put the objects of this class in a global array. How can I count interrupts on a given pin, so that the result is available by using the appropriate object method?

I tried different solutions, but the problem lies in the ISR method, which must be static. This method has no access to object fields, so I do not know where and how to increment the counter of interrupts.

I divided the code into several files. I attach only the necessary to solve this problem.

This holds up my project. Please help.

Main file:

```
#define GPIO_CONFIG_FILE "cfg/gpio.txt"
#define WIFI_AP_CONFIG_FILE "cfg/ap.txt"
#define WIFI_STA_CONFIG_FILE "cfg/sta.txt"
#define AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT 7
#define LED_BUILTIN_OLIMEX 33
#define BTN_BUILTIN_OLIMEX 34

#include "FS.h"
#include "SD_MMC.h"
#include "GPIO_CONFIG.h"

GPIO_CONFIG gpio[AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT];
uint32_t gpio_int_cnt[AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT] = {0};

void setup() {
  if (checkSdCard()) {
    setUpPinsFromFile(GPIO_CONFIG_FILE);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

GPIO_CONFIG.h

```
#ifndef GPIO_CONFIG_h
#define GPIO_CONFIG_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#define ID_LENGTH 7

class GPIO_CONFIG {
  public:
    GPIO_CONFIG();
    void setUp(const char * key);
    void printConfig();
    uint8_t number();
    uint8_t mode();
    uint16_t multiplier();
    bool inversion();
    char * id();
    static void isr();
    static uint32_t int_cnt();

  private:
    uint8_t gp_number;
    uint8_t gp_mode;
    uint16_t gp_multiplier;
    uint32_t gp_init_value;
    bool gp_inversion;
    char gp_id[ID_LENGTH];
    //    const uint8_t gp_mode_array[4] = {INPUT, OUTPUT, INPUT_PULLUP};
};
#endif
```

GPIO_CONFIG.cpp

```
#include "GPIO_CONFIG.h"
GPIO_CONFIG::GPIO_CONFIG() {
  gp_number = 0;
  gp_multiplier = 1;
  gp_inversion = false;
  gp_init_value = 0;
}

void GPIO_CONFIG::setUp(const char * key) {
  //nr|id|name|mode|multi|inv|init
  char cfg[sizeof(key)];
  for (uint8_t b = 0; b < sizeof(key); ++b) {
    cfg[b] = key[b];
  }

  //PIN_NUMBER
  char * tok = strtok(cfg, "|");
  gp_number = atoi(tok);

  //ID
  tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
  for (int b = 0; b < sizeof(tok); b++) {
    if (b < ID_LENGTH) {
      gp_id[b] = tok[b];
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  gp_id[ID_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';

  //NAME
  strtok(NULL, "|");

  //MODE
  tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
  gp_mode = atoi(tok);

  //MULTIPLIER
  tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
  gp_multiplier = atoi(tok);

  //INVERSION
  tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
  gp_inversion = (atoi(tok) > 0);

  //INITIAL VALUE
  tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
  gp_init_value = atoi(tok);

  //0-in; 1-out; 2-int
  if (gp_mode != 1) {
    if (gp_inversion) { //sterowanie podstawowe przez vcc
      pinMode(gp_number, INPUT_PULLUP);
    } else {
      pinMode(gp_number, INPUT);
    }
    if (gp_mode > 2) {
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(gp_number), isr, FALLING);
    }
  } else {
    pinMode(gp_number, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void GPIO_CONFIG::printConfig() {
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("GPIO_CONFIG:");
  Serial.print(" -no:");
  Serial.print(gp_number);
  Serial.print(" -id:");
  Serial.print(gp_id);
  Serial.print(" -mode:");
  Serial.print(gp_mode);
  Serial.print(" -multi:");
  Serial.print(gp_multiplier);
  Serial.print(" -inv:");
  Serial.print(gp_inversion);
  Serial.println("");
#endif
}

uint8_t GPIO_CONFIG::number() {
  return gp_number;
}

uint8_t GPIO_CONFIG::mode() {
  return gp_mode;
}

uint16_t GPIO_CONFIG::multiplier() {
  return gp_multiplier;
}

bool GPIO_CONFIG::inversion() {
  return gp_inversion;
}

char * GPIO_CONFIG::id() {
  return gp_id;
}

void GPIO_CONFIG::isr() {
//  gpio_int_cnt[0]++;
}

uint32_t GPIO_CONFIG::int_cnt() {
//  return gpio_int_cnt[0];
}
```

**@EDIT 2018/01/04 08:10**
I add some changes to files:

Main .ino file

```
isr_ptr isrptr[AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT];
```

GPIO_CONFIG.h

```
#define AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT 7

class GPIO_CONFIG;
typedef /*static*/ void (*isr_ptr)();
extern isr_ptr isrptr[AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT];
extern GPIO_CONFIG gpio[AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT];

(...)

public:
  void setIndex(const uint8_t * i);
  uint8_t index();

(...)

private:
  uint8_t gp_index;
  uint32_t gp_cnt_value;
```

GPIO_CONFIG.cpp

```
void GPIO_CONFIG::setIndex(const uint8_t * i){
  gp_index = *i;
  isrptr[gp_index] = &isr;
}

uint8_t GPIO_CONFIG::index(){
  return gp_index;
}

void GPIO_CONFIG::setUp(const char * key) {
  (...)
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(gp_number), isrptr[gp_index], FALLING);
  (...)
}

void GPIO_CONFIG::isr() {
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<AVAILABLE_GPIO_CNT; ++i){
    if(&isrptr[i] == &gpio[i].isr()){ //here is my actualy problem. how can i compare this?
      gpio[i].increment_cnt_value();
      break;
    }
  }
}

uint32_t GPIO_CONFIG::int_cnt() {
  return gp_cnt_value;
}
```

---

### SOLUTION

Here I place short fragments which have to be modified:

GPIO_CONFIG.cpp

From `isrptr[gp_index] = &isr;` to `isrptr[gp_index] = isr;`

From `if(&isrptr[i] == &gpio[i].isr){` to `if(isrptr[i] == gpio[i].isr){`

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a blog or forum. If you have an **answer** to your **question**, write it as such and accept it (and then revert that last edit). | [ask] | [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I've looked over your code several times and can't find your ISR(s).  I know how to handle this sort of problem in simple C code:  You just define an array with one element for each interrupt pin, and increment that element from its respective ISR.  I don't know how to relate that to what you've shown.

The part that often causes trouble is that you usually need to define variables shared between the main code and ISR as volatile.  Failing to do this can cause problems that are really hard to find, due to the compiler optimizing away things that it decides aren't changed (in the ISR or the main code).

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was editting my ask. I have some idea, but this causes new problem. **@EDIT 2018/01/04 08:10** I add some changes to files and I have problem at GPIO_CONFIG.cpp. `if(&isrptr[i] == &gpio[i].isr()){ //here is my actualy problem. how can i compare this?`